# terraform plan hangs on "requesting state lock"

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, terraform

When running `"terraform plan"`, using local files for state management, it hangs on `"requesting state lock for workspace"`. This is on a new windows box using powershell.

If I `set -lock="false"` it works fine. I've tried deleting the state file and directory and rerunning init, but the only thing that has worked so far was disabling the lock.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:
terraform force-unlock -force lock-id

Example:
terraform force-unlock -force 53029871-ed7c-d58d-77d8-2c3a0f7d59dc

Comment: I get Failed to unlock state: LocalState not locked. Trying to find the lock id I ran "terraform state show 'packet_device.worker'" and it tells me "No state file was found!"

Comment: The above command may not work if your state is local and locked by a local process. If this is the case, try killing the process and retry. For example, try using: Get-Process terraform | Stop-Process -force

Comment: Get-Process says there aren't any terraform processes running. This is on a new machine. Even with a newly created minimalist main.tf, init and validate work just fine but plan hangs on the state lock.